# How to aggregate values in Data Frame for a few columns to have NaN in case of sum NaN instead of 0 in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, aggregate

I have Data Frame in Python Pandas like below:

**Input data:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id' : [999, 999, 999, 185, 185, 185, 999, 999, 999],
    'target' : [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    'event': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-01', '2023-02-03', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03'],
    'survey': ['2023-02-02', '2023-02-02', '2023-02-02', '2023-03-10', '2023-03-10', '2023-03-10', '2023-04-22', '2023-04-22', '2023-04-22'],
    'event1': [1, 6, 11, 16, np.nan, 22, 74, 109, 52],
    'event2': [2, 7, np.nan, 17, 22, np.nan, np.nan, 10, 5],
    'event3': [3, 8, 13, 18, 23, np.nan, 2, np.nan, 99],
    'event4': [4, 9, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 11, 8, np.nan, np.nan],
    'event5': [np.nan, np.nan, 15, 20, 25, 1, 1, 3, np.nan]
})

df
```

[image]

As you can see for id = 999 in column "event5" I have 2 times NaN for that id with event = 2023-01-01.

**Requirements:**

I need to aggregate that Data Frame and sum all values from columns event1, event2, event3, event4, event5 for each id in the same date from "event" column.

For example if id = 999 has 2 rows with event = 2023-01-01 I need to sum all values from columns event1, event2, event3, event4, event5 for taht id to have one row.

I have code in Python Pandas like that:

```
column_names = df.columns
df = df.groupby(["id","target", "survey", "event"]).agg({col: 'sum' for col in column_names if col not in ["id","target", "survey", "event"]})
df.reset_index(inplace = True)
df
```

Nevertheless, when I use that code sum of NaN values return 0, but I want to have NaN if I have to sum NaN values:

[image]

**Example result:**

So, as a result I need to have something like below, where sum of NaNs will be NaN not 0.

[image]

How can I modify my code to achieve that or maybe you have some other idea ?

Answer (score 1):

By default, pandas' [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html) skips NaNs, you can pass `skipna=False`:

```
out = (df.groupby(["id","target", "survey", "event"], as_index=False)
         .agg(lambda x: x.sum(skipna=False))
       )
```

Or use the underlying numpy array, since numpy's [`sum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) doesn't sum NaNs:

```
out = (df.groupby(["id","target", "survey", "event"], as_index=False)
         .agg(lambda x: x.to_numpy().sum())
       )
```

Output:

```
    id  target      survey       event  event1  event2  event3  event4  event5
0  185       0  2023-03-10  2023-01-01    16.0    17.0    18.0     NaN    20.0
1  185       0  2023-03-10  2023-01-02     NaN    22.0    23.0     NaN    25.0
2  185       0  2023-03-10  2023-01-03    22.0     NaN     NaN    11.0     1.0
3  999       1  2023-02-02  2023-01-01     7.0     9.0    11.0    13.0     NaN
4  999       1  2023-02-02  2023-02-03    11.0     NaN    13.0     NaN    15.0
5  999       1  2023-04-22  2023-01-01    74.0     NaN     2.0     8.0     1.0
6  999       1  2023-04-22  2023-01-02   109.0    10.0     NaN     NaN     3.0
7  999       1  2023-04-22  2023-01-03    52.0     5.0    99.0     NaN     NaN
```

##### NaN out only if more than `N` NaNs in

You could also dynamically decide to have a NaN if the number of NaNs is above a threshold, for example ignore 1 NaN but not 2 or more:

```
N = 2
out = (df.groupby(["id","target", "survey", "event"], as_index=False)
         .agg(lambda x: x.sum(skipna=x.isna().sum()<N))
       )
```

Output:

```
    id  target      survey       event  event1  event2  event3  event4  event5
0  185       0  2023-03-10  2023-01-01    16.0    17.0    18.0     0.0    20.0
1  185       0  2023-03-10  2023-01-02     0.0    22.0    23.0     0.0    25.0
2  185       0  2023-03-10  2023-01-03    22.0     0.0     0.0    11.0     1.0
3  999       1  2023-02-02  2023-01-01     7.0     9.0    11.0    13.0     NaN
4  999       1  2023-02-02  2023-02-03    11.0     0.0    13.0     0.0    15.0
5  999       1  2023-04-22  2023-01-01    74.0     0.0     2.0     8.0     1.0
6  999       1  2023-04-22  2023-01-02   109.0    10.0     0.0     0.0     3.0
7  999       1  2023-04-22  2023-01-03    52.0     5.0    99.0     0.0     0.0
```